# SpriteKit - Adding enemy causes frame drop

Tags: ios, scroll, sprite-kit, frame-rate

My game is a side scroller using SpriteKit. The player stays at the same x-position and the obstacles are moving towards him. But whenever I add an enemy the frame rate drops for a short moment. I tried to change many things, like removing the enemy's dynamics or animation. But nothing works.
Here's some code:

```
func addZombie() {
    let zombie = Zombie()
    zombie.position = CGPoint(x: screenWidth + zombie.size.width * 0.5, y: screenHeight * 0.5)

    zombies.append(zombie)
    addChild(zombie)
}
```

The above method creates the enemies. It's called by using:

```
func generateZombies() {
    let wait = SKAction.waitForDuration(2.5)
    let run = SKAction.runBlock {
        self.addZombie()
    }
    runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.sequence([wait, run])))
}
```

I also tried NSTimer, but nothing works. Please help me.

Zombie():

```
class Zombie: SKSpriteNode {

var textureArrayWalking = [SKTexture]()

init() {
    let mySize = CGSize(width: Player().size.width, height: Player().size.height * (4/3))
    super.init(texture: nil, color: UIColor.greenColor(), size: mySize)

    orderTextureAtlases()
    texture = textureArrayWalking[0]

    zPosition = 1

    physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSize(width: (2/3) * self.size.width, height: self.size.height))
    physicsBody?.restitution = 0.0
    physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = enemyCategory
    physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = groundCategory
    physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = playerCategory | bulletCategory | groundCategory
    physicsBody!.allowsRotation = false;

    walk()
}

func walk() {
    runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.animateWithTextures(textureArrayWalking, timePerFrame: 0.07)), withKey: walkingActionKeyZombie)
}

func orderTextureAtlases() {
    let textureAtlasWalking = SKTextureAtlas(named: "ZombieWalking")

    for index in 0..<textureAtlasWalking.textureNames.count {
        let name = "ZombieWalking_JeromeWalk_\(index)"
        let tex = SKTexture(imageNamed: name)
        tex.filteringMode = .Nearest
        textureArrayWalking.append(tex)
    }
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

}

Comment: Does it drop only on the simulator? Or on both the sim and a real device?

Comment: It drops on both.

Comment: By how much does it drop. A small amount is ok cuz it's loading all the info about the item being spawned

Comment: It drops to 40 fps, which is not okay, because as a player you notice it (everytime an enemy is added

Comment: Try commenting out certain (relevant) things one at a time until the problem goes away. From the code I see, I don't see any major problems/causes.

Comment: Try changing the line `let zombie = Zombie()` to something else to check if it's the problem

Comment: It works with another Sprite. What should I do?

Comment: That means that the problem is caused somewhere in your class. Try looking around in there and experiment with different lines commented out

Comment: Now it's working properly. It's because I created an instance of the class Player() everytime a size is assigned to the zombies, because its size should be relative to the player's one. Thank You

Comment: No prob. Glad you could solve your problem